# Pandas/Numpy: Using multiple conditional statements with Numpy where and transform

Tags: r, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

In Python 3, I'm trying to create an indicator column which indicates if two conditions hold for each contract in the data.

(1) If all the outstanding_balance's in for the contract are == 0, then the contract is **Invalid**

(2) If the contract_maturity_date is earlier than the minimum date_report_created, then the contract is **Invalid**.

The data I have is as follows:

```py
import pandas as pd

example_data = {'contract_no': [1,1,1,2,2,2],
                'date_report_created': ['2019-01-01', '2019-01-02', '2019-01-03', '2019-01-01', '2019-01-02', '2019-01-03'],
                'contract_maturity_date': ['2018-01-01', '2018-01-01', '2018-01-01', '2019-01-15', '2019-01-15', '2019-01-15'],
                'outstanding_balance': [0, 0, 0, 20, 0, 0]}
example_data = pd.DataFrame(example_data, columns = ['contract_no',
                                                     'date_report_created',
                                                     'contract_maturity_date',
                                                     'outstanding_balance'])
```

Which looks like this:

```py
   contract_no date_report_created contract_maturity_date  outstanding_balance
0            1          2019-01-01             2018-01-01                    0
1            1          2019-01-02             2018-01-01                    0
2            1          2019-01-03             2018-01-01                    0
3            2          2019-01-01             2019-01-15                   20
4            2          2019-01-02             2019-01-15                    0
5            2          2019-01-03             2019-01-15                    0
```

And I want the data to look like this:

```py
   contract_no date_report_created contract_maturity_date  outstanding_balance valid_contract_flag
0            1          2019-01-01             2018-01-01                    0             Invalid
1            1          2019-01-02             2018-01-01                    0             Invalid
2            1          2019-01-03             2018-01-01                    0             Invalid
3            2          2019-01-01             2019-01-15                   20               Valid
4            2          2019-01-02             2019-01-15                    0               Valid
5            2          2019-01-03             2019-01-15                    0               Valid
```

So far I've only been able to fulfill condition (1), and I'm unsure of how I can add the second condition into the logic.

```py
import numpy as np
example_data['payment_information_in_database'] = np.where(example_data.groupby('contract_no')['outstanding_balance']
                                                                       .transform('sum') == 0, 'Invalid', 'Valid')
```

I'd be very grateful for any help with this problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need apply here:

```
s=df.groupby('contract_no').apply(lambda x:x.contract_maturity_date.lt(x.date_report_created)
&(x.outstanding_balance.sum()==0)).reset_index(drop=True)
df['valid_contract_flag']=np.where(s,'Invalid','Valid')
```

---

```
array(['Invalid', 'Invalid', 'Invalid', 'Valid', 'Valid', 'Valid'],
  dtype='<U7')
```